# Firebase Update just a Parent Node

Tags: javascript, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is a small question and if need be I'll just rewrite everything, but I want to save myself the work.

I have a structure that looks like `users/usernames/<someUN>/`. I checked out the Firebase documentation but I couldn't find examples of how to update in a 'tight' tree.

Now if I want to change `<someUN>`, you can see the problem

```
this.database.ref('users/usernames/' + this.UN).update({
  username: newUsernameVariable
})
```

I would have to restructure an unchangable value and do something like `users/usernames/<userID>/username/<username>` but

1. it goes against denormalizing the database and
2. I already have a tree holding `uids/<uid>/usernames/<UN>`, so that would be extra redundant

Now if you tried to move the ref up a notch:

```
this.database.ref('users/usernames').update({
  this.UN: newUsernameVariable
})
```

*This is very close to what I want* but unfortunately is not valid JSON. The left hand side is not converted to string. I've tried doing this

```
var UNJSON = JSON.stringify(this.UN);
this.database.ref('users/usernames/').update({
  UNJSON: newUsername
});
```

But it won't work, just treats UNJSON as a word

EDIT:

I've changed it to

```
var updates = {};
updates[this.UN] = newUsername;
this.database.ref('users/usernames').update(updates);
```

Which almost works, but now the children node are replaced!

I've changed the question of this title because essentially I've gotten to the point where I have something like `users/usernames/myawesomeusername/{manychildren}` and I want to keep the children while editing myawesomeusername.

EDIT 2: this.UN is populated in onAuthStateChanged by the time it hits the update code. Here is the setting of this.UN

```
// UN is a global read/write username string that persists throughout the session.
// SETTING THE VALUE OF this.UN WITH UID
if(this.UN == undefined) {
  console.log('this.UN was null. Fetch the real one with UID from the database');
  this.database.ref('uids/' + user.uid).once('value', function(snapshot){
    this.UN = snapshot.val().username;
    console.log('Grabbed from snapshot.username');
    if(this.UN == undefined) {
      console.log('Impossible error');
    }
  }.bind(this)).catch(function(err){
    console.log('Error obtaining userID from database', err);
    this.UN = user.displayName || "User" + user.uid;
  }.bind(this));
} else {
  console.log(this.UN);
}
```

I use `this.UN` to handle any time I need the username for the rest of the app.

Comment: What is the value of `this.UN`?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Updated with an explanation, thanks!

Comment: Instead of the entire flow, can you reduce the problem to a hardcoded value for `this.UN`?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Hm by hardcoded value do you mean like replacing `this.UN` with a string literal? That would work, but `this.UN` needs to change depending on who is logged in.